# how to complete order review and send to the users email adress specified while placing the order as a confirmation massage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

hello i was following a tutorial on a javascript mastery video on creating an ecommerce web shop everything was ok it uses stripe for payment but i dont want to use online payment i want to use payment on delivery but the customers should receive order summary via email after placing order
this is the link to the github project i want to modify if someone can help me modify or modify it for me and push it to github i  will apreciate to download and review how it was archived am new to react https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_e_commerce

Comment: Stackoverflow is for asking about specific problems, not essentially asking people to code entire projects for you.

Comment: itsnot coding the entire project its removing the stripe and sending order email the project is already coded just a litle modification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need **backend** to store **users** and **orders**, then it will be easy to send mail with **order summary** after user placing order.

Comment: iam using commerce js to store and upload the product can i use webhook with it